# Group values of keys in ruby hash in one hash and print specific value

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

This is my hash:

```
{"Specialty"=>"Other (note in description);Medical;Dental;Vision", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com/ca"}
{"Value"=>"P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060"}
{"Specialty"=>"Pharmacy;Medical", "Value"=>"800-824-0898"}
{"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Medical", "Value"=>"800-700-9186"}
{"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Emergency Care;Medical;Chiropractor;Acupuncture", "Value"=>"800-677-6669"}
{"Specialty"=>"Pharmacy;Medical", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com"}
{"Specialty"=>"Claims", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com/consumer/claims/claimsoverview"}
{"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Emergency Care;Medical;Chiropractor;Acupuncture", "Value"=>"https://example/example/apps/services/www/ABCBS/mobilewebapp/default/index.html#/providers/search"}
{""Specialty"=>"Claims;Customer Service;Medical", "Value"=>"800-888-8288"}
```

You can see from this that the key `value` has differed `values` in each hash table, and I would like to print only one specific value, that is `P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060`

I tried printing the values of the hash by `hash["value"]` and it prints all the contents of the values. I tried loading them into an `array[]` by using `to_s` function to print the value I want, but one array is loaded with all these values or I may be loading the array wrong.

```
array = []
array = medical.split("\n")
text = array.to_s
text1 = array.index{|s| s.include?("P.O.")}
puts text1
```

Can someone help me with how do I print that specific hash value inspite of various values existing in the key named `value`

Comment: first of all, that is not a hash, but multiple hashes, are they in an array? second why do you know which value you want to have? because there is no `Specialty` key there or what ?

Comment: I have no clue why the downvote for this question. This is my query and I have done my research that I have mentioned. If you find this query odd or very basic, stackoverflow does not define anywhere that basic questions should not be ask. kindly refrain from downvoting, if this wouldnt help you, it would help a newbie!

Comment: To be clear, it wasn't me who downvoted the question! I just ask some question so i can answer without guessing. Sorry if I sounded rude, that wasn't intended! But to be honest, there are quite some informations missing, which would justify a downvote in SO terms. The reason i didn't downvote was, that I can see you tried, and with a little update everything will be fine. So take the chance, supply more information, and hopefully you will get rid of the downvotes. Good luck!

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I am sorry that message wasn't intented to you. I mean, if there was any information that is needed, there is always comments section to ask for it?

Answering to your previous question, I am asserting a particular content received from the db to the mobile application and hence i wanted to store that particular value of the key somewhere than a group of all the values for that key. 

On a side note, will provide all the information from the next question. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It is okay, I saw you allready got an answer, but as you can see he had to guess first what you want. All I want is to explain to you why you got downvoted, so that you can avoid it next time. Then SO will be a great site for you. Just put someting in your question like `"I want to fetch the Value which contains 'P.O. BOX'", or "I want to fetch the value of the hash without a 'Specialty' key"` for the next time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) @DoktorOSwaldo

Comment: The other thing to know about SO is that you can edit your question to improve it.  I'm voting to close it because it doesn't meet SO standards, but if the question were edited to make it more clear what you were asking for, it can be kept open (or re-opened, if it has been closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the pattern of the `hash` specifically, uniqueness I can figure out is that all hashes have multiple keys except the one you are looking for..considering it as an array of hashes

```
hashes.each{ |hash| break hash['Value'] if hash.keys == ['Value'] }
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments, instead of printing the hashes individually you can check and print the required value directly..

```
results1.map{ |result1| (value = result1['Value']).include?('P.O. BOX') ? value : nil }.compact
```

It will return array of strings having substring `P.O. BOX`

Comment: Tried this `puts results1.each{ |result1| break result1['Value'] if result1.keys == ['Value'] }`  the interpreter crashes.

Tried this  `puts result1.each{ |result1| break result1['Value'] if result1.keys == ['Value'] }` 
It prints all the hash tables again.

and yes! result1 is the multiple hash table displayed above and it is not loaded into an array yet. May be i am not understanding what are you trying to convey in your code

Comment: what's the source of the data? how do you get it? Ideally it should be array of hashes.

Comment: i am fetching it from the db and it returns me in the form of hash when I iterate each row in the results that are returned. How I have put in the question is the exact result received.

Comment: when you say you are `iterating` that means there's an enumerator present. can you add that code where you are iterating?

Comment: `results1 = db.query medicalquery
results1.each do |result1|
  puts result1
`

Or I even tried filtering in the results that are received by having puts result1["value"]` instead of just `result1` where it prints values values of that key

Comment: It returns this when i print `result1["Value"]`when i iterate.. 



`P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060
800-824-0898
800-700-9186
800-677-6669
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/consumer/claims/claimsoverview
https://m.example.com/example/apps/services/www/ABCBS/mobilewebapp/default/index.html#/providers/search
800-888-8288`

Comment: Thanks! I understand, but I am not sure why its returning me this error when I try to print the required value by your method `include?': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: my bad..typo. it should be parantheses

Comment: Damn! Even I forgot all about it!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your have an array of hashes and you want to search for 'P.O.' strings then you can do this:

```
arr.select { |hash| hash["Value"][/P\.O\./] }.flat_map(&:values)
#=> ["P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_hashes = [
    {"Specialty"=>"Other (note in description);Medical;Dental;Vision", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com/ca"},
    {"Value"=>"P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Pharmacy;Medical", "Value"=>"800-824-0898"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Medical", "Value"=>"800-700-9186"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Emergency Care;Medical;Chiropractor;Acupuncture", "Value"=>"800-677-6669"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Pharmacy;Medical", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Claims", "Value"=>"https://www.example.com/consumer/claims/claimsoverview"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Urgent Care;Emergency Care;Medical;Chiropractor;Acupuncture", "Value"=>"https://example/example/apps/services/www/ABCBS/mobilewebapp/default/index.html#/providers/search"},
    {"Specialty"=>"Claims;Customer Service;Medical", "Value" => "800-888-8288"}] 

> array_hashes.select{|h| h["Value"].include?("P.O.")}.flat_map(&:values).first
#=> "P.O. BOX 60007 LOS ANGELES, CA 90060"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, May I ask how did you manage to load multiple hash tables into one array?

Comment: I am sure you are getting result in an array from wherever you are fetching records but as you have print so it shows individual